# Puppet: Is it possible to supply additional information when realizing an exported resource?

Tags: puppet, puppetdb

Suppose I want `hostB` to have a distinct file for each puppet node, but with owner that is only known to the `hostB`.

Theoretically it can be done, if we allow `hostB` to write a custom fact (`my_special_owner`), and then read that fact via `query_facts` function in the `my_resource` definition by `hostA`. But that seems too dirty: it pollutes the facts namespace with meaningless stuff, possibly causing name clashes. It is also a lot of coding for such a simple thing.

Here is a mockup of what I have in mind:

```
define my_resource() {
  $owner=${my_collector::owner} #This attempt fails
  file{$name: ensure=>exists, owner=>$owner}
}

node hostA {
  @@my_resource{"/tmp/file1.tmp"}
}


class my_collector($owner) {
  # How to pass $owner to the collector below?
  My_resource <<| |>> 
}

node hostB {
  class {'my_collector': owner=>bob}
}
```

Comment: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_resources.html#amending-attributes-with-a-collector not working?

Comment: I didn't find it. I wrongly assumed that all information about resource collectors will be on their dedicated  https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html page... If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this section](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_resources.html#amending-attributes-with-a-collector) for Puppet documentation about customizing collector attributes.  Example:

```
File <| |> {
  owner => 'foo',
}
```